# Is every integer a rational number?

Tags: rational-numbers

Why is this the case? $0$ is an integer and it can't be divided by $0$...

It's on my textbook, as it says

> We conclude that every integer is a rational number, and so the rational numbers form an extension of the integers.

Comment: What is the issue about not being possible to divide by $0$?

Comment: Well, for every integer $n$, we can write $n$ as a quotient of integers - namely $n/1$. $0$, in particular, can be written as $0/1$.

Comment: $0$ can be divided by $1$.  $0 = \frac 0 1$.   Why did you think $0$ would have to be divisible by $0$.  Nothing in the definition of rational, tells you *what*  the denominator has to be.

Comment: OP, you're not understanding the definition. We can express 0 as two integers $a \over b$. Take $0 \over b$ where $b$ is any integer, as others have pointed out in this thread.

Comment: @DanielMishan: It is $\frac{0}{b}$ where $b$ is any integer except zero. The definition of a rational number does specify that the denominator shouldn't be zero.

Comment: My apologies, @Axion004, you are correct. Except zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your comments you are confusing "Every rational number can be written as $\frac ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers" (which is true) with "Every $\frac ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are integers, is rational" (not true; $b$ can never be equal to $0$).

$0$ is rational because $0 = \frac ab$ where $a = 0$ and $b = 1$.

But $\frac 00$ is not rational because it is meaningless garbage.  $\frac 00$ (which is *not* the same thing as $0$; not even *close* to the same thing as $0$) is not a number or anything at all.  It is undefined.  It is meaningless garbage.

P.S.  All integers are rational because for any integer $k \in \mathbb Z$ then $k = \frac k1$.

A text with a more careful definition might state that to be rational it must be expressible as $\frac ab$ where $a$ is an integer and $b$ is a natural number.  This not only rules out $\frac k0$ but also avoids ambiguities an problems of $\frac {k}{-m}$ vs $\frac{-k}{m}$.

Comment: Restricting the denominator to be a natural number doesn't solve the problem of multiple representations of the same number. There are always reducible fractions.

Comment: "Restricting the denominator to be a natural number doesn't solve the problem of multiple representations of the same number. "  Did anyone ever say it did?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you need to be able to divide 0 by itself? The defining characteristic of a rational number is typically taken to be that it can be represented as a ratio of two integers, and zero can certainly be represented this way (for example, as 0/1).

Comment: But in the case of 0/0

Comment: Zero over zero is undefined. If you want to make an integer inti a fraction, just throw it over 1. Done.

Answer (score -2):

Zero over zero is sometimes called an [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form), especially when dealing with limits, and it's *not* necessarily garbage. Yep, it usually is, but depending on context, you can use it to do useful calculation if you're careful and understand what you're doing.

For example,

$$\frac{0}{0} = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x} = 0$$

is legitimate as I understand it.

Comment: $\frac00$ is always meaningless except as suggesting the form of a limit, not as actually being a fraction. Your equation is nonsense. Only the rightmost equals sign makes sense.

Comment: You understand wrong.  $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac {x^2}x -=0$, and $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac x{x^2} =\infty$,  But It is *not* acceptable to refer to either of those as $\frac 00$.